# How to update an element in dynamic array by a specific index?

Tags: arrays

How to update an element in a dynamic array by a specific index?

I know how .push() property works for a dynamic array but I am trying to add an element providing an index so the transaction reverted with no explanation.

```
contract TestArray { 
   uint[] public id;

   function updateByIndex(uint _id, uint _index) public {
        id[_index] = _id;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided should never work since it would always fail the Solidity bounds checks which assert that the `_index` your are trying to access should be less than the length of the array. Arrays in Solidity differ from mappings, as they are tied to a `length` parameter that gets incremented everytime you push new elements to the array.

In previous versions of Solidity (i.e., v0.5.x), it used to be the case that the `length` parameter of an array was writable. The following code would've worked:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.x;

contract TestArray { 
   uint[] public id;

   function updateByIndex(uint _id, uint _index) public {
        if (_index + 1 > id.length) {
            id.length = _index + 1;
        }
        id[_index] = _id;
   }
}
```

The code above basically increments `length` conditionally so that the array index you are trying to access is always less than `length` and the code doesn't revert due to bound checks.

But at the time of writing with Solidity v0.8.x, this is no longer the case. The `length` parameter is currently read-only, and the only way to increment it would be to append new elements to the array via `push`.